# What is $a^n\bmod n$ for composite $n$?

Tags: number-theory

While [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) states that
$$a^p\equiv a\pmod p$$
for any *prime* number $p$, which may be considered a consequence of [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)
$$a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1\pmod n\tag{e}\label{e}$$
(for $n\nmid a$) since $\phi(p)=p-1$ for $p$ prime, I was wondering

> whether there is any similar statement one can make about $a^n\bmod n$ when $n$ is not a prime number.

As a simplest example, take $n=p^2$ such that $\phi(n)=p(p-1)$, so
$$a^{p^2}\equiv a^{\phi(p^2)+p}\stackrel{\eqref{e}}\equiv a^p\pmod{p^2}$$
or for $n=pq$ with $p\neq q$ (i.e. $\phi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)$)
$$a^{pq}\equiv a^{\phi(pq)+p+q-1}\stackrel{\eqref{e}}\equiv a^{p+q-1}\pmod{pq}$$
(assuming $n\nmid a$), but these are rather "boring" identities...

I also wonder whether the [exponential cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Exponential_cycle_length)
$$a^{\lambda(n)+k}\equiv a^k\pmod n$$
plays a role here...

Comment: You may be interested in [Carmichael numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number).

Comment: @lhf Interesting numbers, thanks! So my question now boils down to "Appart from Carmichael numbers $b$, where $b^n\equiv b\pmod n$..." ;) Hm, also interesting then: [Knödel numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kn%C3%B6del_numbers) (though at first glance Wikipedia seems to contradict [the Mathworld entry](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KnoedelNumbers.html))

Comment: @lhf Thanks again for your comment, it lead me to Knödel numbers and an actual answer (assuming it is correct...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [$\lambda(n)+v_\max(n)\leqslant n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/545773/163), the $k\geqslant v_\max(n)$ in the exponential cycle
$$a^{\lambda(n)+k}\equiv a^k\pmod n$$
can be chosen as $k=n-\lambda(n)\geqslant v_\max(n)$ to obtain
$$a^n \equiv a^{n-\lambda(n)} \pmod n$$
As special cases, observe that for prime numbers (and Fermat pseudoprimes), where $\lambda(n)=\phi(n)=n-1$, this yields Fermat's little theorem; while the two examples from the question are also included.

Note how this yields $n\in K_{n-\lambda(n)}$, i.e. each (composite) $n$ is a [Knödel number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kn%C3%B6del_number)

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2938577/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque Great, thanks!